# Fractions and invitations

Tags: analysis, fractions

Diane sent out 25 invitations to her birthday party.  If 1/6 of the invitations were for her family, about how many invitations were for her family?  Please show your work and explain.

Answer (score 2):

Translate to math.

The key to answering "word problems" of this sort is being able to translate the given information into mathematical operations involving the data provided. Key words here are "of" and "about".

"**About** one-sixth **of** the (25) invitations sent were for her family."

$\iff \text{About}\;\dfrac 16 \underbrace{\times}_{\text{OF}} 25\,$ of the invitations were for her family.

$\iff \dfrac 16\times 25\, =\, 4.1\overline{66} \underbrace{\approx}_{\text{about}} 4$ invitations were for her family.

Answer (score 1):

Your data says that $25 \cdot \frac 16 = 4\frac 16$ were for her family.  What it means to get $\frac 16$ invitation, I don't know.

Comment: Notice the "about" in the phrasing of the question.  It's really poorly stated, and I fear that it's coming verbatim from an actual textbook .. sad.

Comment: @Doc:  the about should be on the $\frac 16$, rather than on the $4$.  Clearly we were expected to round it off, but I agree it is badly written.

Comment: These answers didn't deserve downvotes, certainly not downvotes with no explanation. Anyway, here's my two-cent's worth: +1